# Laravel - how to use paginate with parameters

Tags: pagination, laravel-5.5

How can I use pagination with vuejs and laravel

I first used this in order to have my posts with users,categories and photo.

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $posts = Post::with('user', 'category', 'photo')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
    return response()->json([
        'posts' => $posts,
    ], 200);
}
```

All works, but now I want to add pagination and for some reason it does not work. I did like this:

```
$posts = Post::with('user', 'category', 'photo')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5)->get();
```

How can I make my pagination work?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you just need to take out the get() from the end:

```
$posts = Post::with('user', 'category', 'photo')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
```

When I use paginate I skip the get().

Answer (score 0):

The paginate method looks for a `page` query string argument on the HTTP Request. It probably doesn't work if it's not present. You seem to be creating a route meant for an API. If that's the case, it's quite likely you don't have the `page` variable set in your HTTP request. You can check the presence of this variable or create your own paginator: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator